# Python DataFrame groupby on kmeans results don't show all categories

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I would appreciate any feedback on why this might be happening:

I have a hourly speed dataset that has 24 columns of speed data (for 24 hours a day) for many roads (therefore data has size 90000, 24). Then I performed kmeans analysis on the data which allowed me to add one more column - "kmeans categories" to the dataset. Now it has 25 columns  - 24 columns of hourly speed data and 1 column of category data (say, with 8 unique values 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7). I then wanted to compute for each kmeans category the average hourly speed so that I can end up having a 8 row 24 columns dataset with each row being a kmeans category. However with the codes below I am only getting 5 rows and 24 columns of data. the 5 rows are for 0-4 and I was expecting to get 8 rows for 0-7. What could have gone wrong???

code:

```
speed_kmeans= speed.groupby(['kmeans']).mean()
```

Comment: Are you sure you have 8 categories? what gives `speed['kmeans'].nunique()`? if 8, what gives `speed_kmeans.shape`?

Comment: Yes I am sure I have 8 categories. I did a value_counts that showed a distribution of datapoints over 8 different k-means categories

Comment: So there is **no obvious reason** why using `groupby` would discard some categories from the computation. if you don't give a reproductible example, we can only guess. once again, what gives  `speed_kmeans.shape`? you say you are *only getting 5 rows* which sounds to me as you are only seeing the first 5 rows with the method `head` for example or that some display options are set to 5 rows max, just trying to be sure it is not a display problem